# bank atm tcp message load blancing and routing using java nio/netty and activemq

Tags: tcp, activemq-classic, netty, load-balancing, nio

I am designing banks ATM message processing/routing framework, and need some help in finalizing the technologies and architecture. Transactions comes from multiple ATM's of partner banks, say currently we serve 5 to 6 banks and not more then 10 ATMS per bank.

1. Messages come from ATM via tcp socket and are received by multithreaded Java process called ATM controller. It runs in blocking mode with one thread per socket. Every bank is given a unique port where all its ATM send messages.
2. Message is converted to ISO8583 format sent to Hardware security module(HSM) for decryption via tcp sockets, PIN verification is also done using another software module. these are standard libraries which is working fine so far.
3. Messages are then sent to another Java program which is called Transaction router, again via tcp sockets. transaction router will route the message to either local system for in-channel banks or NPCI gateway for non-channel banks transaction.

The current system is built using core java and blocking threads but it has following areas of pain

1. Messages gets lost in transit.
2. Timeouts happening very frequently which results in offline reversal of transactions at our database. we need to send response back to ATM within 15 second max.
3. No means of recovery if there is a system shutdown or power outage.
4. No load balancing at either controller or router program.

To eliminate these pain areas we are redesigning system and considering following technologies

1. Java Nio2 for non blocking threads , or maybe Netty or Mina since in future we anticipate more banks and atms to get serviced by our system. Or blocking io is sufficient for our needs ??
2. ActiveMQ for queuing messages to make is persistent during transit.
3. Nginx or HAProxy for tcp load balancing.

Questions I have are

1. If I used java Nio2 at ATM controller and Transaction router then do I need a mechanism to insert a correlation id to be inserted in messages so that I can sent response back to correct socket, since non-blocking is async mode so one thread might be servicing multiple sockets.

**EDIT**

Got some further clarifications on the requirements,

1) Our TCP connections once established with Banks ATMs,are never supposed to terminate, unless there is some network issue. So for every request, we need to first do a keep alive check before we send a response bcoz it a long running connection.

2) We are expecting 500 to 800 concurrent non-terminating tcp connections. Also when the ATM first starts up due to reboot or maintenance, it needs to exchange some config data with the server, and further requests should always hit the same server which has cached this config data.

Q1) So if I go by experts suggestions to use JMS based approach with blocking threads per connection, how can I do a keep alive check before sending response.

Q2) If I need to run tcp server in high-availability mode what should be approach. ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly advise you *against* using NIO for this. What you need to do is debug your existing system. You'll only make it worse with NIO.

Comment: Does the request-response at non blocking nio server-socket thread works the same way as blocking thread socket or any special field needs to be inserted in the payload at the server-code listener to identify the correct server-socket for sending response due to its async nature ?

Comment: No. I suggest you should be looking at a JMS-based solution for this.

Comment: Does Nginx and HAProxy work at layer 4 for load balancing incoming tcp socket connections or they are used only at layer 7. What should be the limit on max concurrent sockets beyond which load balancing becomes necessary ?

Comment: @Amit Too broad. I will only repeat that there is nothing wrong with a blocking-mode thread-based architecture. What you're up against is either a wrong technology choice in the first place (low-level TCP as against a message broker) or mere bugs in the code. NIO is not a solution to either.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your use case with ATM and financial transactions you should not start by looking at complex low level non blocking solutions.

Go for transactional JMS messaging all the way and blocking I/O. You won't be overrun by messages so you should very easily be able to calculate max load (all ATM machines used at the same minute). That can't be very high even if you have thousands of connected ATM machines. This is a typical case where reliability and less code complexity (less bugs) comes before scaling. Hardware is cheap and you won't likely hit high peak loads.